# MapReduce program keep counter when reading a text file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to implement a map reduce program so that the output is the diagonal of a .txt file. **For example**, reading the file

```
a*****
*b****
**c***
***d**
****e*
*****f
```

I'd like the output to be **abcdef**.

The mapper class I ve written is this one:

```
public class MapperClass extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>
{
//hadoop supported data types
private static final Text t = new Text("");
private Text word = new Text();
//private static int linenumber = 0;

  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
  {
        //taking one line at a time from input file
        String line = value.toString();
        int linenumber = 0; 
        word.set(Character.toString(line.charAt(linenumber++)));
        output.collect(word, t);
   }
}
```

But the output I get is

```
a
*
*
*
*
*
```

I tried to put the line-number out of the map method but still got the same result. Can someone help? I just need to find a way to keep a counter which gets incremented when I read the next line from a file.
**P.S.** I think there is no need of a reducer here as I dont want to sort any intermediate results. Correct me if I am wrong.
**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

Use the `LongWritable key` parameter that is already provided to your `map` method and points to the line number in the processed file.

Typically, you cannot keep track of the `linenumber` in your mapper, as a file may be processed by multiple mappers (especially if you're using `TextInputFormat` which assumes that regular text files are [splittable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.html#isSplitable(org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path))). This kind of global state usually only makes sense in counters.

Comment: I tried something like this (assuming each line is 6 chars long)                    int position = ((int) key.get() / 6) % 6;                                                                    word.set(Integer.toString(position));                                                               Problem is that I get the letters in sorted order (Instead, Id like them to appear one after another e.g first letter of first line, then letter of second line etc.. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I think you need to explicitly call `job.setNumReduceTasks(0)`, otherwise you'll end up using the `IdentityReducer` and the shuffle and sort will still take place. Do you see any reducer task being spawned for your job ?

Comment: Yes there was one reducer task being spawned. I added `job.setNumReduceTask(0)` but I experienced something weird. As an input I have a .txt file with 12 rows, 4 letters each row. Then with `word.set(Integer.toString((int)key.get()));`
    `output.collect(word, t);`                                                                            the output was 0,5,10,15,20,25,30. Shouldnt it continue till 60??           I dont undertstand why this is happening

Comment: Does the job succeed ? Are there any exceptions in the log ?

Comment: Yes it does. There are no exceptions in the log

Answer (score 0):

Enable the `private static int linenumber = 0;` line in static scope.

And comment the `int linenumber = 0;` line in the mapper method.

Yes of course, you dont need a reducer for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are not using any loop there, so it is traversing in the first line itself. Try this

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
{
    //taking one line at a time from input file
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(line.toLowerCase());
    int linenumber = 0; 
    while(itr.hasMoreTokens()) {

    word.set(Character.toString(line.charAt(linenumber++)));
    output.collect(word, t);
    }
}
```

Hope it will work

Comment: Are you getting any error or can you tell me what is the status of your job

Comment: I tried with a different file now containing the lines (a,ab,abc) and I get  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2

Answer (score 0):

All lines do not execute in map function together. They execute line by line .
First time when you will use linenumber++ it will give  you 'a' but next time linenumber will also set to 0 so '*' will be sent to reducer function. Use context counter for these type of problem.